# Mostrar productos de woocomerce, en sitio padre

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

tengo la siguiente pregunta.

Tengo un sitio en wordpress, el cual contiene 2 sitios hijos.

sitioPadre
sitioPadre/sitioHijo1
sitioPadre/sitioHijo2

en sitioHijo1 y sitioHijo2, tengo dos woocommerce, con productos distintos.

Mi consulta es la sigueinte.

Quiero mostrar 4 productos de cada uno de los sitiosHijos, en el sitioPadre(que este no tiene woocommerce) y que lógicamente, al hacer "click" me redirecciones al producto, ejemplo "sitioPadre/sitioHijo1/producto/producto-prueba"

Es posible esto?

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones suelen terminar como cerradas. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con un iframe por ejemplo, hay puglins que te permiten crear Iframes.
No te redireccionan si no que los ves desde la propia pagina padre.